# Angular 2 Meteor - TypeScript 'Cannot compile module unless the --module flag is provided

Tags: angular, meteor, typescript, angular2-meteor

I am following this [Angular 2.0 Meteor Tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping).
I followed all the steps extactly, adding and removing specified modules. Installed the last versions of Meteor and of VS Code.

The tutorial claims that System.js is available 'out of the box' as a module loader, included into the Angular2-meteor package. It does not seem to work for some reason, as I get an error in VS:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/angular2-meteor.d.ts" />

import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.

I found nothing useful on other answers on the subject, especially because in my case the --module flag has to be provided to the TS compiler which is automatically loaded by the angular2-meteor package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by reinstalling the whole stack (meteor, VSCode and all the packages). Don't know but what it was caused exactly but it seems to be some package version issue.